# Create a copy of tab item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, tabs

I have in xaml file one `TabControl` and one `TabItem` which contains a `ListView`. I want to add new tabs dynamically with the same `ListView` schema.

I tried to do this like so:

```
ListView newList = new ListView();
newList = my_xaml_listview;
```

I then tried to insert this in a new `TabItem`. The problem is that this code returns me a reference to my original `ListView`.

How can I create a new copy with the same `ListView` schema (same columns, colors etc) and add it in a new `TabItem`?

Comment: When it comes to columns/colours/etc, this seems like a perfect candidate for a style. You can then create a new `ListView`, assign your style in code and assign the `ItemsSource` so that the columns match. If they're pointing to the same collection view, you can use the existing `ListView`'s `ItemSource`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to create a style for listview, i add the colors,margins etc but i can't add the columns names, width etc. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, I will post the code in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, when it comes to colours/margins/sizings you can use a `Style` as a resource which I believe you already have.

For columns, you'd do exactly the same thing, but with a `GridView` as a resource and share that across each `ListView` that you create.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <GridView x:Key="MyViewGrid">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Column 1" Width="100" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="Column 2" Width="100" />
    </GridView>
</Window.Resources>
<ListView View="{DynamicResource MyViewGrid}" />
```

.. and in code:

```
myNewListBox.View = (GridView)Resources["MyViewGrid"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Iclonable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx)

And try this [Iclonable sample](http://csharp.2000things.com/2010/11/07/143-an-example-of-implementing-icloneable-for-deep-copies/)